# ¿Necesito conectar una app de rails a access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ms-access, mdb

Necesito abrir una base de datos de access con rails, para poder trabajar con las tablas en esa base de datos, si alguien a trabajado con db de access me pueda ayudar.

Saludos

Comment: bienvenido, te sugiero leer [ask] de paso también hacer el [tour] para que de ese modo comprendas mejor como funciona la plataforma, debes darle en editar y agregar lo que llevas y que fallos has tenido

Comment: ¿Es para una conexión permanente o solo para extraer/leer una vez? Lo ideal sería evitar utilizar Access, sobre todo en un ambiente productivo y simplemente importar la información a mysql/postgresql; utilizar Access sería el último recurso que recomendaría.

Comment: Es solamente para extraer la información una vez

Comment: Al ser una lectura única, te recomiendo hacerlo manualmente, es decir, exportar desde _Access_ la información a _MySQL_ (o a la base de datos que tengas en tu aplicación).

Comment: ok, muchas gracias